# Unity launcher and java chat windows

Tags: unity, launcher, java

I'm using java 7 to talk in this italian chat [LIbero](http://digiland.libero.it/)

When I open several dialogue windows, unity launcher shows me only 1 icon and, when I click on it, only the last dialogue window appears and I can't see the others.

What can I do?